# In-place crop of a <canvas> portion in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've a `<canvas>` with an image already loaded and all the graphics coordinates needed for a crop (x, y, w, h) in an array.

What I'm trying to do is to **crop the canvas directly**, without a temporary other canvas to copy to/from (as suggested in other SO answers).

My idea is to:

1) Draw the selected area on the top-left corner of the canvas

2) Shrink the canvas size to the area

```js
$('#edit').on("click", function() {

  var img = $('#canvas');
  var c = img[0];

  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  //var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);

  ctx.drawImage(c, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);

  c.width = 100;
  c.height = 100;
});


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 350, 350);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
<input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
```

Seems easy to me, but I'm missing something: when I execute, I get nothing https://jsfiddle.net/qg0znpu7/

What's wrong with my code? how can I fix it to obtain an in-place canvas crop?

Comment: The downvote without a comment really, really helps  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `width` or `height` of a `canvas` will **clear** it. For that reason you will have to copy the data first.

You can use [`putImageData()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_putimagedata.asp) for that:

```js
$('#edit').on("click", function() {
  var c = $('#canvas')[0];

  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);
                                   
  c.width = 100;
  c.height = 100;

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
});


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 350, 350);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
<input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
```

Comment: Ok, `getImageData` + `putImageData` works, but you get better performance if you save the #canvas content to a new in-memory canvas (`var memCanvas=document.createElement('canvas') ...`) and then `drawImage` that memCanvas back to the resized #canvas (`ctx.drawImage(memCanvas,0,0)`).

Comment: @markE Thanks for the info. But why is that faster? Do you have any links/speed test to show that? Would be realy interesting

Comment: @CodeiSir your're my today-hero! works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @markE: thanks you too for your tip. For now I go with CodeiSir, but I bookmarked your tip for a future improvement.

Comment: Both imageData operations are not hardware accelerated by the GPU (if a GPU is available) while drawing to a second canvas is accelerated. Also, imageData creates and transfers a Uint8ClampedArray of R,G,B,A pixel data which is more expensive than canvas-to-canvas copies.

Comment: @markE now I understand^^ ofc drawImage would be faster. But you would have to clone the old canvas first, as you might have some attributes attached to it and also swap it in the DOM. I'm not sure if it's still faster after doing so

Comment: In my experience, copying+from a tempcanvas is faster than pixel copying -- but situations vary. :-) BTW, You're just creating the temporary canvas to hold the content while resizing the on-screen canvas -- no cloning or DOM swapping involved. ;-) Since you're recopying the temp contents back to the original on-screen canvas any on-screen canvas attributes would nicely remain intact. F.Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/1rtvuLfq/

Comment: @markE clever solution! Sorry I didn't think about that